# Querying SQL for user permission

Tags: sql

I have a database that stores usernames and permission that I need to query to get a list of users and their associated permission. It appears that they are both stored in two tables (dbo.user and dbo.[permission set]), but I can't seem to figure out how to query so that I get the following results:

```
User 1, perm 1
User 1, perm 2
User 2, perm 1
user 2, perm 3
```

Comment: could you show the table definitions? also, mysql, sqlserver, oracle....

Comment: Do you realize that you haven't specified almost anything about your scenario? We can't just guess the database structure, you should at least show some effort if you want a stranger on the internet to help you. Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that every user has an id and an entry in the permissions table, and every row in the permissions table has a corresponding user_id column, you'll want to use a JOIN command for this. It'll probably end up being something like this:

```
SELECT user.name, permission.perm
    FROM user
    JOIN permission ON permission.user_id = user.id;
```

Comment: Oops; Thank you. Edited to reflect the nature of the potential column better.